# iPad Opengl ES program works fine on simulator but not device

Tags: ios, ipad, opengl-es-2.0, glsles

For the device, all of my shaders load fine except one. For this shader program I get "Fragment program failed to compile with current context state" error, followed by a similar error for the vertex shader when I make a call to glGetProgramInfoLog(...);

Vertex shader:

```
#version 100

uniform mat4 Projection;
uniform mat4 Modelview;
uniform mat4 Rotation;
uniform vec3 Translation;

uniform vec4 LightDirection;
uniform vec4 MaterialDiffuse;
uniform float MaterialShininess;

attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec3 normal;

varying vec4 color;
varying float specularCoefficient;

void main() {
    vec3 _normal = normalize(mat3(Modelview[0].xyz, Modelview[1].xyz, Modelview[2].xyz)*normal); 
    // There is an easier way to do the above using typecast, but is apparently broken

    float NdotL = dot(-_normal, normalize(vec3(LightDirection)));
    if(NdotL < 0.0){
        NdotL = 0.0;
    }
    color = NdotL * MaterialDiffuse;
    float NdotO = dot(-_normal, vec3(0.0, 0.0, -1.0));
    if(NdotO < 0.0){
        NdotO = 0.0;
    }
    specularCoefficient = pow(NdotO, MaterialShininess);

    vec3 p = position + Translation;
    gl_Position = Projection*Modelview*vec4(p, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 100
precision mediump float;

varying vec4 color;
varying float specularCoefficient;
uniform vec4 MaterialSpecular;

void main(){
    gl_FragColor = vec4((color + specularCoefficient*MaterialSpecular).rgb, 1.0);
}
```

I am not sure what is going on, especially since I have a similar program that is exactly as above with the addition of texture coordinates. Also, I checked the compile status of each shader when I linked the programs using glGetShaderiv(theShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result) and they all checked out fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Usually the info log gives you the exact line where the error occurred. Does it give a specific line number?

Comment: No it doesn't. Exact log is: "Validation Failed: Fragment program failed to compile with current context state.

Validation Failed: Vertex program failed to compile with current context state."

Comment: Also, I checked the compile status of each shader when I linked the programs using glGetShaderiv(theShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result), and they all checked out fine. (Edited question to reflect this fact).

Answer (score 1):

Changing the line

```
gl_FragColor = vec4((color + specularCoefficient*MaterialSpecular).rgb, 1.0);
```

in the fragment shader to

```
gl_FragColor = vec4((1.0*color + specularCoefficient*MaterialSpecular).rgb, 1.0);
```

fixes the problem. I suspect it has something to do with precision related to the varying variable color, for a reordering of the line to

```
gl_FragColor = vec4((MaterialSpecular + specularCoefficient*color).rgb, 1.0);
```

works as well.