# GLSL program fails intermittently on some iOS hardware

Tags: ios, ipad, opengl-es-2.0, glsles

I'm running into a problem where changes to a fragment shader temporarily break rendering. The shader compiles; there is no error condition or log output from the compile step, the link step, or glValidateProgram(). But subsequent calls to glDrawArrays() return GL_INVALID_OPERATION, nothing is drawn, and the app becomes very slow or unresponsive.

However, when I switch from my main development device (an iPad 2) to other hardware (an iPhone 5s and an iPad Mini) the same code runs perfectly. Strangely, if I then reconnect to the iPad 2, the problem goes away and I can continue to develop the shader on that device. This same cycle has repeated several times now: I revise and add a bit of new code to the shader and the problem resurfaces. I switch to the newer devices, the code runs fine, switch back to the iPad 2, the problem mysteriously goes away (sometimes) and I can continue working. Once it starts working again it seems to keep working. With the code below, however, I now seem to be stuck at a point where the workaround is not helping.

My hunch (or hope) is that something in my code is getting past the compiler but is somehow dicey in a way that some hardware accepts it (A7 and SGX 543) but some doesn't (SGX 535). Maybe the intermittent nature of the workaround is just a red herring. If nothing like that leaps out, I'd welcome any other troubleshooting suggestions.

The code is long so I've excerpted the portions relevant to this most recent iteration of the problem. Previous iterations involved adding just a few lines of seemingly innocuous code.

```
uniform highp vec3  vertexColors[3];

mediump vec3 hexagonLayer (highp float edge1, highp float edge2, int layer, mediump vec3 underColor, highp float opacity) {
    highp float opac = remap (length (faceP - vertexFacePositions[layer]), 0.0, edge1 * 3.0, 1.0, opacity);

    mediump vec3 shadowColor = pow (underColor, vec3 (2.0));
    highp float shadowOpacity = (1.0 - smoothstep (edge1, edge1 + SHADOW_WIDTH, 1.0 - trilinears[layer])) * SHADOW_OPACITY * opac;
    mediump vec3 color = mix (underColor, shadowColor, shadowOpacity);

    return mix (color, vertexColors[layer], (1.0 - smoothstep (edge1, edge2, 1.0 - trilinears[layer])) * opac);
}
```

Comment: You may have already considered this but the intermittent nature makes me wonder if it's a memory issue in your objective C code maybe a vertex buffer. You could try running the application on the simulator with "Enable Guard Malloc" on.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, at least partially. My first mistake was that my glValidateProgram() code was never being called. Turns out I had an error message after all, albeit unhelpful:

```
Validation Failed: Fragment program failed to compile with current context state.
Validation Failed: Vertex program failed to compile with current context state.
```

So lesson number one is that there can apparently be a compilation failure even when both GL_COMPILE_STATUS and GL_LINK_STATUS are good, and both logs are silent.

Thanks to a clue from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050840/ipad-opengl-es-program-works-fine-on-simulator-but-not-device) I started looking at mismatched precision qualifiers, and sure enough changing all my mediump colors to highp solves the problem. Is that because I declared my uniform as highp, and then mix() between a highp and mediump vec3? (I shortened the code in my question to show the relevant sections.)

It makes some sense to me that this might accidentally work on the newer hardware, as I think I remember reading somewhere that GLES-3-capable hardware treats highp and mediump as the same bit depth. I would love some confirmation of that guess.

Comment: Precession hints are often to blame.